# Working with Checkbox in Struts

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I am having a Registration page in struts 1.2.I am having five checkbox in JSP Page as below.

**Register.jsp**

```
<html:checkbox property="userSkills" value="Java" name="UserJava">Java</html:checkbox>
<html:checkbox property="userSkills" value="Php" name="UserPhp">Php</html:checkbox>
<html:checkbox property="userSkills" value="MySQL" name="UserMySQL">MySQL</html:checkbox>
<html:checkbox property="userSkills" value="JS" name="UserJs">Javascript</html:checkbox>
<html:checkbox property="userSkills" value="Oracle" name="UserOra">Oracle</html:checkbox>
```

**Bean class**

```
public class UserDetails extends ActionForm 
{
    private String UserJava;
    private String UserPhp;
    private String UserMySQL;
    private String UserJs;
    private String UserOra;
        .
        .
        .

        //getters and setters
}
```

I am confused with this.Should I create five Class Variables in bean corresponding to the five check box in the JSP page or is there any easy alternative.Anyhow I am going to store the values which i get in checkBox as CSV in database.

The number of form elements in form should it match the class variables in the bean?

Thanks for Reply

Answer (score 1):

You need just one String-Array:

```
public class UserDetails extends ActionForm {

    private String[] userSkills;
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

The array contains the check values ("UserJava","UserPhp" ...)